# Can I enable Kerberos authentication for Oracle 11g Database Standard edition?

Tags: oracle, kerberos

I have an Oracle 11g Database Standard instance running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I need to enable Kerberos authentication. I followed the documentation for activating Kerberos 5, but cannot get it to work.

So I was wondering, is this functionality only available for higher edition and if yes, is there any tricks to enable it on a Standard edition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos authentication is a part of Advanced Security Option (ASO). Per Oracle support note  549989.1 which is valid for 9.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.3: "ASO can only be used with Enterprise Edition software and requires a license."

You can confirm it with Oracle Net command `adapters | grep -i kerberos` which should show a line similar to:

```
Kerberos v5 authentication
```

if you have ASO installed.

Comment: I am running Windows but this command seems to be a UNIX command unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, this command is not present on Windows. You can still verify via OUI graphical interface (that is, installer).

Comment: Clearly the ASO components are not even installed with Standard edition.

Comment: [No longer part of Advanced Security](https://oracle-base.com/blog/2015/06/27/native-network-encryption-not-part-of-advanced-security-option/) - no additional licenses needed now